# python 2.7 : appending log return to csv

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, logging, append

With the following code I'm trying to grab data from a website every 5 mins, timestamp it, calculate its logn return and append all that to a csv file.

Grabbing the data, time stamping it and appending to csv works, but when I try to figure out how to include the log return I'm kind of stuck.

```
import time
from time import strftime, gmtime
import numpy as np
import urllib2
from urllib2 import urlopen
from math import log

coiAr = []
dateAr = []
logReAr = []

def mcapGrab():
    while True:
        try:
            sourceCode = urllib2.urlopen('http://coinmarketcap.com').read() 

            mcapUSD = sourceCode.split('<strong>Total Market Cap: <span id="total-marketcap" data-usd="')[1].split('"')[0]
            coiAr.append(float(mcapUSD.replace(',','')))

            date = strftime('%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S', gmtime())
            dateAr.append(date)         
#           if len(coiAr) > 0:
#               indexLog = 1
#               logRe = log(coiAr[indexLog]/coiAr[indexLog-1])
#               logReAr.append(logRe)
#               indexLog += 1
#           else:
#               logReAr.append(0)

            for eachMcap in coiAr:
                saveLine = date+','+str(eachMcap)+'\n'
                saveFile = open('mcapdata.csv', 'a')
                saveFile.write(saveLine)
                saveFile.close()

                s = 0
                print dateAr[s]+','+str(coiAr[s])
                time.sleep(300)
                s+= 1


        except Exception, e: 
            print 'Failed to grab market cap', str(e)

mcapGrab()
```

I've commented out the section where I attempt to calc and append log return but doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is your expected output? What happens instead when you uncomment your lines?

Comment: Are you reading data into `coiAr` first? You are not using the list, not really, as you append **one** item, then write out that one item to your CSV file.

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the log based on the *previous* value you wrote to the CSV file?

Comment: when I uncomment those lines I get: Failed to grab market cap list index out of range
13 Jan 2014 15:08:19,12608482759.0,0.0. And yes, I am trying calc the log based on the previous value in the `coiAr`.

Comment: You get an `IndexError`, most likely, because you only have one entry at index 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use global lists; just write each entry to the file *as you find it*. Using the `csv` module would make this all a bit easier still:

```
import csv

sourceCode = urllib2.urlopen('http://coinmarketcap.com').read() 
mcapUSD = sourceCode.split('<strong>Total Market Cap: <span id="total-marketcap" data-usd="')[1].split('"')[0]
mcap = float(mcapUSD.replace(',','')

# read previous value from the CSV first
with open('mcapdata.csv', 'rb') as infh:
    last = None
    for row in csv.reader(infh):
        last = row[1]  # second column

# Now calculate the log value based on the last value
logRe = log(mcap/float(last))

# write new values
with open(mcapdata.csv', 'ab') as outfh:
    date = strftime('%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S', gmtime())
    csv.writer(outfh).writerow([date, mcap, logRe])
```

This code will read the `mcapdata.csv` file, picking out just the last value written to it. You could instead also keep all of the rows in memory and just picking out the last entry in a list of lists.

Comment: I think I got it now. Thanks!